# How to make Keyboard Button message text different from its caption in Telegram bot API using C#

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

I need my bot to print a different message than its caption (which shows by telegram client on keyboard button element).

My custom button has this text: `"Where am I?"` and when I click on it, it prints on the screen `"Where am I?"` also.
I want the button to print `"/location"`.(something different from its `text` field)

How can I achieve it? I'm using `C#` and `Telegram Bot API`

***EDIT:***

**What I want:**

- When the user clicks this button, telegram client send a messages with `/age` [as his typed message] but **NOT** send `show my age` (which is that button `text` field )

So: I want a button with a `text` . when the user clicks the button I want the message sent to be different from that `text`.

Comment: but it is not possible to have a message different than your text. 

text- String->Text of the button. If none of the optional fields are used, it will be sent to the bot as a message when the button is pressed

Comment: That's what I wanted to know :) thanks!

Comment: so I put it in the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a boolean field for location, did you set it to true?
https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#keyboardbutton

**Update:**
hen you are sending a reply to the user, you are also sending a ReplyKeyboardMarkup. 
ReplyKeyboardMarkup has a field called keyboard which is Array of Array of KeyboardButton. 
on each KeyboardButton you have a bool for location that you need to set to true if you want that button to send the location

**Update 2**

it is not possible to have a message different than your text. text-    String->Text of the button. If none of the optional fields are used, it will be sent to the bot as a message when the button is pressed

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. My code was an example, I have a lot of buttons and any of them needs that custom command. Is there a way to achieve it?

Comment: Hi, When you are sending a reply to the user, you are also sending a ReplyKeyboardMarkup. right? ReplyKeyboardMarkup has a field called keyboard which is Array of Array of KeyboardButton. 
on each KeyboardButton you have a bool for location that you need to set to true if you want that button to send the location

Comment: I will add it to the answer too

Comment: I think we miss understanded: my question is not the location, my question is the custom keyboard message

Comment: So you want to show the location to the user? If so, you have to do it in your response. when you get the message you have the location if the checkbox is true, then send it back as the response to the user

Comment: I did it, try to have a look at the question now

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at [InlineKeyboardMarkup](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinekeyboardmarkup) instead of `ReplyKeyboardMarkup`? It solves your problem.

---

**UPD**
Basic usage

```
  public static InlineKeyboardMarkup TestInlineKeyboard { get; } = new InlineKeyboardMarkup           
    {
        InlineKeyboard = new []{new[] {new InlineKeyboardButton("Text1","Data1"), new InlineKeyboardButton("text1","data2")} }
    };
```

where `"Text1"` and `"text1"` are captions of the inline buttons, `"Data1"` and `"data2"` is `CallbackQuery` text, which your bot will receive when user clicks inline button.

Note, that bot sends not any message to user when he clicks inline button. If you need to send any message at that moment - you can do that programmatically.

Comment: can you post something like a basic usage? I don't really understood how the array of keyboards can solve it

Comment: Warning: Inline keyboards are currently being tested and are not available in channels yet. For now, feel free to use them in one-on-one chats or groups.
but very good to know. Thanks for sharing it

Comment: Beware that the `callback_query["message"]["text"]` is not coming from `inlinekeyboardbutton` label. It is coming from the message associated with it.